# How to plot a line chart by type of file by moth using python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-visualization

I have a dataframe and I want to plot a line chart showing the size of each file in time. 
Currently I am just plotting 1 line. But how can I plot all of the files?
I guess I have to modify the shape of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file_type': ['file'] * 1 +  ['file.png'] * 1 +  ['file.PNG'] * 1 + ['file.csv'] * 2,
    'size': [11] * 5,
    'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *1 + ['2020-02-01 23:00:34'] * 2 + ['2020-03-01 23:00:34']*1 + ['2019-01-02 23:00:34']})


df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.normalize()
group1= df['file_type'].str.lower().str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False).fillna('unknown')
group2 = df['created_at'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

df.groupby([group1, group2])['size'].sum().reset_index()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Use seaborn style defaults and set the default figure size
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20, 4)})
df['size'].plot(linewidth=0.5);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seaborn.lineplot` with `hue`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='created_at', y='size', hue='file_name')
```

To have multiple lines for each file type, do this:

```
# do not reset index but unstack:
(df.groupby([group1, group2])['size'].sum()
   .unstack(level=0).plot(subplots=True)
)
```

Comment: But how can I make it for each type of file?

Comment: Each type of file is a line in that plot.

Comment: How can I make the plot bigger? Is it possible to do that with seaborn?

Comment: Do a `plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))` before that plot. Also you can pass `layout=(num_row, num_col)` to `plot()`.

Comment: I have more than 1000 files. So it is difficult to see them all. Is it possible to filter just the firts 13 lines with higher values? I have tried this: ```.sort_values(ascending=[False]).head(13)``` But it does not accept ```head(13)```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like so with [`sns.lineplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='darkgrid')
sns.lineplot(x='created_at', y='size', data=df)
```

Comment: But how can I make it for each type of file?